# How can I check if a vertex (index) is in a given componentTag (string) of a MFnMesh using Maya 2022 C++ API?

Tags: c++, maya-api

I am given a componentTag by name (string) and want to check if a given vertex (index) from a MFnMesh is part of that componentTag using the Maya 2022 (or 2023) C++ API.

Any ideas, hints or otherwise are highly appreciated.

Stephan